# how to use jQuery to handle specific types of html controls

Tags: jquery

Creating a click event for an input is easy

```
$('input').click(function () {
                alert('adsf');
        });
```

But how can I be selective so that the previous code only works on type checkbox or of type button, rather than using the generic 'input' selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some built-in [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) like `:checkbox` and `:button` to find these elements easily.

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
    alert('checkbox');
});

$('input:button').click(function () {
    alert('button');
});
```

There's also `:radio`, `:submit`, `:text`, and `:input` selectors, among others

Comment: `input:checkbox` is probably a more efficient selector, no? Your selector will query the entire DOM for if its a checkbox, whereas this will limit that search to the `input` elements.

Comment: `:checkbox` is just short hand for `input[type=checkbox]`

Comment: narrowing down `input:checkbox` is redundant, also

Comment: @yc, reading this: http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/, you're absolutely right

Comment: @yc glad to hear it :) The only reason I knew that was that I remember reading somewhere (possibly a Paul Irish blog post) that the `:checkbox` selector is from Sizzle, and it's a known source of inefficiency.

Comment: @hunter, thanks that's exactly what I was looking for, but I do agree with modifying it according to yc.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this page](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) in the jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){});
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){});
//or
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){});
$('input:button').click(function(){});
//or combined, this is probably the best solution in your case
$('input:button, input:checkbox').click(function(){});
```

2 different approaches. Doesn't matter which one you use. Both to exactly the same. I think the best is to have both selectors together if possible in your case.